# Unable to set up data source as aws s3 via cli and test_yaml_config in great_expections

Tags: great-expectations

great_expectations setup:

Created a new virtual environment
Installed required packages:

```
pip install boto3
pip install fsspec
pip install s3fs
```

Updated data source in configuration: great_expectations.yml

```
datasources:
  pandas_s3:
    class_name: PandasDatasource
```

Steps to reproduce this isse:

```
> great_expectations init
Would you like to profile new Expectations for a single data asset within your new Datasource? [Y/n]: Y
Enter the path of a data file (relative or absolute, s3a:// and gs:// paths are ok too)
: s3://my-bucket-name/

We could not determine the format of the file. What is it?
    1. CSV
    2. Parquet
    3. Excel
    4. JSON
: 2
```

Getting below error:

**Cannot connect to host s3.amazonaws.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]**

Note: I have the setup for aws ready.
~/.aws has credentials file with below content.

```
output = json
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id = api-key
aws_secret_access_key = secret-key
aws_session_token = sesssion-token
aws_default_acl = None
```

With the same above setup,

Note: Below code works fine:

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

def pd_read_s3_parquet(key, bucket, s3_client=None, **args):
    if s3_client is None:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), **args)

print(pd_read_s3_parquet(key="books.parquet", bucket="books-bucket-ge"))
```

So, connection through ge library blocks the way.

Facing same issue with V3 batch_request API using test_yaml_config.

Using version 0.13.10

Blocked on this, please suggest ways to get rid of this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the poster created this GitHub issue for this question: https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/2541. Please use it to track any further conversations.